# electron builder: how to customize the string values in NSIS installer?

Tags: windows, electron, customization, nsis, electron-builder

- I'm using electron builder, my target is windows nsis
- I've been looking at this links https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis#custom-nsis-script and https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Category:Tutorials to find an easy way to customize my installer but no luck so far, so the question is:
- **What's the easiest way to customize the string values like "only for me" in the following pic**

[image]

Comment: I don't think the point is what I want it to say, but let's say I wanna put "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" instead, can I do that? is it customizable? how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a Electron custom page implemented in [multiUserUi.nsh](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/master/packages/app-builder-lib/templates/nsis/multiUserUi.nsh) and the text is defined in [assistedMessages.yml](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/master/packages/app-builder-lib/templates/nsis/assistedMessages.yml). It looks like [nsisLang.ts](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/master/packages/app-builder-lib/src/targets/nsis/nsisLang.ts) is used to convert the .yml file to a temporary .nsh include file.

It might be possible to use the [Electron NSIS include feature](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis#custom-nsis-script) to include your own custom file. Depending on when it is included it might be possible to override the string:

```
; NSIS include file:
!pragma warning push
!pragma warning disable 6030 ; Disable multiple use warning
LangString onlyForMe 1033 "Just me and only me" ; 1033 is English
!pragma warning pop
```

If that does not work then you must manually edit assistedMessages.yml instead.

Comment: Only changing it manually worked, but I can't use it as a solution, it's really helpful tho, many thanks :)

Comment: @AhmedMohamed Ask the Electron people for a fix, they could allow you to add defines to override strings.